# SQL Errorr: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

insert into supplier(supplier_id, supplier_name, city, state, total_spent)
values
(300, 'Time Manufactures', 'Redwood city', 'California', 90500),
(400, 'Roundhouse inc.', 'New York City', 'New York', 78150),
(500, 'Smith Berries', 'Portland', 'Oregon', 114600),
(600, 'Wesson LLC', 'Yuma', 'Alaska', 32000),
(700, 'ICF Foods', 'Orlando', 'California', 78700),
(800, 'Cheffmans inc', 'Toledo', 'Georgia', 187500),
(900, 'Samwoods Drinks', 'Portland', 'Georgia', 17800);

it give me error while running.
can anyone tell what i mistaken here?

SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: If you are using Oracle 23 (or later) then there is nothing wrong with your statement [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4MZTvwYa). If you are using an earlier version of Oracle then the problem is that you are using an earlier version of Oracle that does not support that syntax. Either use the latest version of Oracle or a different multi-row insert syntax that is supported.